# Finding stationary solutions and verifying differential equations

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

> Consider a trimolecular system where the following chemical reactions occur: 
>   $$\ce{A + B ->[k_1] A + C}\tag1$$
>   $$\ce{A ->[k_2] B}\tag2$$
>   $$\ce{C ->[k_3] C}\tag3$$
>   Write the differential equations that model the evolution of the three component molar concentrations and determine the stationary solutions (there are two). Finally, if initially $[\ce{A}]=0.75$, $[\ce{B}]=0.25$ and $[\ce{C}]=0$, calculate the time when the mole fraction of $\ce{A}$ is half of its initial value.

I think that the differential equations, following the expression for the reaction velocity, are
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t}=-k_2[\ce{A}]$$ 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t}=-k_1[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]+k_2[\ce{A}]$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{C}]}{\mathrm{d}t}=k_1[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]$$
However, I don't know how to proceed with the stationary solutions. I guess that one of them would be obtained doing:
$$-k_1[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]+k_2[\ce{A}]=0$$
but I'm not sure.

Finally, I got the relations 
$$[\ce{B}]=\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{k_2}{k_1}\right)\exp\left(\tfrac{k_1}{k_2}(-\tfrac{3}{4}+[\ce{A}])\right)+\frac{k_2}{k_1}$$
$$[\ce{C}]=-\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{k_2}{k_1}\right)\exp\left(\tfrac{k_1}{k_2}(-\tfrac{3}{4}+[\ce{A}])\right)+1-\frac{k_2}{k_1}-[\ce{A}]$$
but I have no idea how to obtain the time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of $C-> C$ with rate constant $k_3$ ??

Comment: That's in the problem statement, and it doesn't give more information about it... I'm physicist and I got no idea about chemistry, so I cannot give you the answer

Comment: Shouldnt the rate equation for A be $\\\frac{d[A]}{dt} = - k_2[A] + k_1[A][B]\\$ ?

Comment: @SoumikDas No, because A is neither spent nor produced in the first reaction.

Comment: And, is the time required for the mole fraction to become half or the moles? Can you check again ?

Comment: I got $\frac{d[A]}{dt}=-k_1[A][B]$ (that's the left term of the first equation)$+k_1[A][B]$ (that's the right term of the first equation)$-k_2[A]$ (that's the left term of the first equation). Why do you get this equation?

Comment: The third equation still makes no sense, even if it is a part of the problem statement. Also, what is a stationary solution and why do you think you need one?

Comment: A stationary solution will verify the time derivative is null. And I don't know why I need them, it's part of the statement

Comment: Well, then you don't need many equations to do that. A goes to B and never goes back, B goes to C and never goes back, so in the end there will be only C (and maybe some B which can't transform due to the lack of A).

Comment: From $k_2$ simply calculate the half-life of reaction (2).

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differential equations are correct.

From $\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = -k_1[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]+k_2[\ce{A}] = 0$ follow the stationary solutions $[\ce{A}] = 0$ or $[\ce{B}] = \frac{k_2}{k_1}$.

Reaction (2) obeys a first order decay law. Its [half-life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life) is $t_{\frac{1}{2}} = \mathrm{ln}(2) / k_2$.

The image below shows how $[\ce{B}]$ reaches the stationary state soon after the reaction has started ($k_1 = 0.3, k_2 = 0.2$).

[image: k1=0.3, k2=0.2]